# Remove double quotes "" in groovy string in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy

def registry_txt = "base"

def registry_txt_new = registry_txt.minus("") =>prints "base" not base

What is the right regex to use with replaceAll?

Expected result : base

Comment: println registry_txt should print base without the ", but what you are seeing is the console printing the return value of the expression, which is the same as the value you're assigning to the variable. It's probably adding the quotes to show that the return value is a string.

Comment: I am getting in the console as   [Pipeline] echo
"base"

Comment: .minus("\"")  prints base"

Comment: Try your code in `https://<JENKINS_URL>/script` , both `println registry_txt` and `println registry_txt_new` return `base` . I believe Mzzl comment explains what you are seeing.

Comment: Yes but in jenkins console echo $variable wont wont print "" but for me it does..

Answer (score 0):

To remove the closing double quotes I had to use groovy split('"')..Now works